# checkbox set value to model in form with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am tring make a form , and this form hava many checkbox ,

I want to get checkbox value , and set it to model,

this model will submit to service

here is my code

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="add()">
  <dl>
    <dt>Manager Id</dt>
      <dd ng-repeat="user in User.user" >
        <input name="userName[user.userId][]" type="checkbox" 
          ng- model="newProgram.program.managerId" 
          ng-true-value="{{user.userId}}" ng-false-value="{{user.userId}}" check />
          {{user.userUsername}}
       </dd>
   <dt>Member Id</dt>
     <dd ng-repeat="user in User.user">
       <input name="userName[user.userId][]" type="checkbox" 
         ng-model="newProgram.program.memberId" value= "{{user.userId}}" check />
         {{user.userUsername}}
     </dd>
 </dl>
 <div class="form-actions">
   <button type="submit" 
    ng-disabled="form_edit.$invalid || isUnchanged(newProgram)" >Add</button>
</div>
</form>



angular.module('elnApp')
  .directive('check', function () {
    return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl, $filter){ 
          elm.bind('click', function() {
            scope.$watch('newProgram.program.managerId', function (value){
               // set {{user.userId}} to ngModel
              }

          });
        });
    }
  }
});




angular.module('elnApp')
 .controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, programService, userService) {
  $scope.master= {};

  $scope.add = function () {
    programService.add({

  }, $scope.newProgram, function (data) {
    $location.path('/grid');
  });
};

$scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
  return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
};

$scope.User= {'user': userService.query()};

 });
```

I search about many data , but there is nothing???

please help

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest approach I could think of.
http://plnkr.co/edit/vVuV59Vwc6wJ8ptBcfmI?p=preview

I suggest the use of dev console of the browser when something
seems not working.  Also, starting from the simplest implementation.

js:

```
<input type="checkbox" check="model" value="{{ value }}"/>
```

html:

```
app.directive('check', function() {
  return {
    scope: { model: '=check', value: '@' },
    link: function( scope, elem ) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        var value = elem.attr('checked') ? scope.value : null;
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.model = value;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: ok, I tried your suggestion, but my model's value still unchanging

Comment: brands.push(checkValue);
ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(brands);