# checkbox set model value unchanging

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie with AngularJs and ,

I am tring to make a form project with $resource ,

I don't have anyideas to get multiple checkbox value and set it

to model , but there is an error show for my checkbox's value is empty from

service ?

here is my code

```
<dd ng-repeat="user in User.user" >
  <input name="userName[user.userId][]" type="checkbox" ng-model="newProgram.program.managerId" 
    value="{{user.userId}}" check="model" />
    {{user.userUsername}}
</dd>


angular.module('elnApp')
  .directive('check', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: { model: '=check', value: '@' },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl, $filter){ 
        elm.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$watch('newProgram.program.managerId', function (value){
              if(value == true){
                var checkValue = scope.value;
                var brands = [];
                brands.push(checkValue);
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(brands);
                scope.$apply();

              }


          });
        });
      }
   }

 });
```

I am so confused about that , anyone ideas ?

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle or plunker? I'm confused about what you want to do.

Comment: What do you want your directive to do exactly?

Comment: I am tring to make form and get form value to serviece

Comment: possible duplicate of [checkbox set value to model in form with AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248191/checkbox-set-value-to-model-in-form-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems with your code than the one I'm going to point out, but one mistake I noticed is that you shouldn't be using `elm.bind('click', ...)` in your `link` function. The way your code is written, the watch won't be set up until after the element is clicked, but you really want the watch set up right from the beginning.

Just run `scope.$watch` from inside your `link` function, with no `elm.bind`, and you should see some improvement. In other words, your link function should look like:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl, $filter) { 
        scope.$watch('newProgram.program.managerId', function (value) {
          if (value == true) {
            var checkValue = scope.value;
            var brands = [];
            brands.push(checkValue);
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(brands);
            scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      });
```

I don't fully understand the rest of what you want to do ("get form value to service" really isn't very clear to me -- seeing an example on jsfiddle or plunker would be much easier to understand), so this is all the help I can give you. I hope it's useful.